# How is the answer score calculated?

Tags: support, faq-suggestion

Refering to my answer on [Why does zoom not work for one of the openlayers base layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67507/why-does-zoom-not-work-for-one-of-the-openlayers-base-layers/67733#67733).
I am the first to answer and my answer has been accepted and i have 2 upvotes + the bounty. So i was hoping to get the enlightened badge, but i haven't got it yet. 
I think the my answer score is more than 20, but it does not look that way. So maybe i have calculated the score incorrectly. My question is

How is the score for question and answer calculated?

Comment: enlightened badge:
First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=enlightened%20badge.

The wording

> First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more

is indeed ambiguous, but the clarifications offered there show that "score" is synonymous with "net upvotes," so the bounty doesn't help. (Nevertheless, although the bounty of +50 is irrelevant, with its reputation-equivalent of 5 upvotes and three net upvotes, you haven't even (yet) earned the equivalent of +10 upvotes reputation for this answer.)

Incidentally, answers with +10 net upvotes on this site are rare: most questions are sufficiently specialized that few readers feel qualified to vote responsibly on the answers.  The ["Nice answer" badge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) (awarded for +10 net upvotes) has been awarded for just three percent of all answers. The "Enlightened" badge (of which there is at most one per thread) has been awarded on less than 1.5 percent of the threads.

Comment: I get it now, reputation and scores are different. Hope you get this badge again for this answer.